# Iframe - 500 internal server error in live site

Tags: iframe

I have used iframe in my local machine. It works fine.
But when I use it in my live server, it shows 500 Internal server error.

My local machine is windows OS.
Live machine is Linux.

If somebody issue like this, pls guide me

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error is not an issue with anything involving an iframe. It is instead a server side issue.

Some things to check, to possibly help you:

- Is the site configured correctly?

If it is, and you can access the content without an iframe then, it must be another issue.

- Is the iframe set up correctly, and is it providing enough data for a response?

Something to remember about iframes is that they are nothing different to accessing the page directly. If you can access the page on the live site without the iframe, the iframe is misconfigured. If you site is dynamic (e.g Using PHP) then it is more likely for misconfiguration or server errors to occur from bad configuration or queries.

This is the best answer I can provide with the provided data.